# How to do the RESET test on an AR model?

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive, nonlinear

```
> library("lmtest")
> a = arima.sim(list(ar = c(.05, -.05)), 1000)
> b = arima(a, order = c(2, 0, 0))
> resettest(b)
**Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute**
```

Question 1. What I am doing is shown above. What should I do about that?
(I have tried to put in `type`, `data` and `power` parameter at `resettest()`, result is the same.)

Question 2.If I want to do the same thing on the model below

[image]

which is a ar(2) model plus [image], how to fit this nonlinear model (by using R, thank you!)?

Comment: I am sorry if these questions are way too fundamental :(  New on this field.

Comment: Seems it s an unpopular field :) guys plz! if you just passed by and know someone who is good at this field, feel free to tag them! thank you so much!